# What's the best way to add methods to Apollo data objects?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Say I get a `user` object from a query in my props. How do I get all objects of `type User` to have certain methods, eg `.isAdmin()`?

```
isAdmin() {
  return this.groups.contains('admin');
}
```

I know I could add `isAdmin` as a schema field with a resolver for it on the server, but I don't want to add load to server and add size to the response body.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to add a method to the data, but just pass the data to the method instead.

`function isAdmin(user) {
  return user.groups.contains('admin')
}`

And then:

`isAdmin(user)`

Comment: Why? There are pretty strong benefits to OOP

Comment: And strong disadvantages too!